# Sort generic collection?

Tags: c#, sorting

Lets say that I have a generic list.

```
IList<T> list;
```

I need to sort the items in place, but I can't use .NET methods like `Sort` because most collections don't have one. Since I don't know ahead of time what the type will be, how can I sort the items?

```
public void Sort(IList<T> list) {
}
```

Comment: Answers from [poke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15325178/368379) and [BrokenGlass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15325176/368379) are both correct. You will be able to sort collections of objects as long as they implement `IComparable`. I have made generic implementations, which uses this for their advantage and can be found in my [github repo](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Havarti/tree/master/Cheesebaron.Havarti/Sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QuickSort implementation:

```
static void QuickSort<T>(List<T> a, int left, int right) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    T pivot = a[(left + right) / 2];
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (a[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
            i++;
        while (a[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            T temp = a[i];
            a[i++] = a[j];
            a[j--] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        QuickSort(a, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        QuickSort(a, i, right);
}
```

This is what `List.Sort()` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to sort items of some type in a list they [must be comparable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), so for .NET you will have to assume `T` implements [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Now that you can compare the items it's just a matter of implementing a sorting algorithm e.g.:

- [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)
- [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Both are O(n*log(n)) but for an interview I would stick to Merge sort because I find it easier to implement. I think the point here of picking one would be to **not** suggest something completely simplistic with a bad run time, e.g. [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for a large number of sorting algorithms.

You don’t need to know the type as long as there is an order between them. You can ensure that by requiring `T` to be a subtype of [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx).

Comment: That being said, I doubt you would need to do that for *generic* types in an interview. Usually it should be okay to assume that you have a simple type like integers.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is actually two problems: how to compare two elements to see what order they should be in, and how to put them in order.

To compare two elements, you can ask the caller to pass in something to do the comparison, or use [Comparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx) to create one for you.

To put the elements in order, I recommend implementing a QuickSort.